# Reference Dynamic multidimensional table

Tags: lua, lua-table

I have a data structure of nested tables that can be N deep.  for example

```
local data = {
  [1] = {
     [1] = { "stuff" },
  [2] = {
     [1] = { "stuff" },
     [2] = { "more stuff" },  
     [3] = {
        [1] = "deeper stuff"
     }
  }
}
```

Now I can reference "deeper stuff" via data[2][3][1]  But is there a way that I can store the 2-3-1 as a key so I can reference this data[key] ?

I am storing a set of actions that are transformed and looped over in a denormalised table.  I want to be able to reference that this particular action came from a specific point in the original data table.  As this is n levels deep is there a dynamic way of writing [2][3][1]...[n]?

Comment: You can write a function `deep_index` and invoke it as `deep_index(data, 2, 3, 1)` or `deep_index(data, {2, 3, 1})`

Comment: your code causes an error due to mismatching curly braces btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have a single multi-dimensional key. The only way to achieve something like that would be to have some string like `"2-3-1"` which you then use in an `__index` metamethod that tranlates it to the separate keys.

```
setmetatable(data, {
  __index = function(t, k)
    for index in k:gmatch("%d+") do
        -- insert fancier error handling here
        if not t then error("attempt to index nil") end
        t = rawget(t, tonumber(index))
    end
    return t
  end
  })

  print(data["2-3-1"]
```

Alternatively you use a table as key

```
setmetatable(data, {
  __index = function(t, k)
    for i,v in ipairs(k) do
      if not t then error("attempt to index nil") end
      t = rawget(t, v)
    end
    return t
  end
  })

  print(data[{2,3,1}]
```

There are of course more ways to implement the table access in __index.

If data is global you could also use `load` and do something like

```
local k = string.gsub("1-1-1", "(%d+)%-?", "[%1]")
local element = load("return data .. k")()
```

But please don't make data global just so you can do this.

Or you write a function that does that without using metamethods as Egor suggested...

Comment: thank you for this. This works for reading and I am using the Table version but when I write to the table via this - I get an extra table added onto the end of the table rather than updating the reference.  EG

Comment: `{
 [1] = {
  [1] = "~~KeyPress~~",
  [2] = "/cast [nomod] 26573",
  [3] = "~~KeyRelease~~",
  ["Type"] = "Action"
 },
 [2] = {
  [1] = "~~KeyPress~~",
  [2] = "/cast [exists] 123456",
  [3] = "~~KeyRelease~~",
  ["Type"] = "Action"
 },
}`  Becomes the following when I write back to the first point:

Comment: ```{
 [1] = {
  [1] = "~~KeyPress~~",
  [2] = "/cast [nomod] 26573",
  [3] = "~~KeyRelease~~",
  ["Type"] = "Action"
 },
 [2] = {
  [1] = "~~KeyPress~~",
  [2] = "/cast [exists] 123456",
  [3] = "~~KeyRelease~~",
  ["Type"] = "Action"
 },
 ["table: 000001A7E014F570"] = {
  [1] = "~~KeyPress~~",
  [2] = "/cast [nomod] 26573",
  [3] = "/cast [nomod] 26573",
  [4] = "~~KeyRelease~~",
  ["Type"] = "Action"
 }
}```

I am expecting that in the first table entry should be replaced with the 4 line table with the 2nd element duplicated rather than the appended table at the end.

Comment: From your example How do i `data[{2,3,1}] = newvalue`

Comment: please ask a new question. adding so much stuff in comments is not ideal