# Writing to Dynamic Multidimensional table via path

Tags: lua, lua-table

Following on from [Reference Dynamic multidimensional table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66414614/reference-dynamic-multidimensional-table)

i have a data structure like

```
local data = {
  [1] = {
     [1] = { "stuff" },
  },
  [2] = {
     [1] = { "stuff" },
     [2] = { "more stuff" },  
     [3] = {
        [1] = "deeper stuff"
     }
  }
}
```

I have added onto it the following metadatatable

```
  __index = function(t, k)
    for i,v in ipairs(k) do
      if not t then error("attempt to index nil") end
      t = rawget(t, v)
    end
    return t
  end
  })

  print(data[{2,3,1}]
```

This is great for getting data but when I try to set the data it instead creates a new table.  For example `data[{2,3,1}] = "Updated Stuff"` turns data into

```
  [1] = {
     [1] = { "stuff" }
   },
  [2] = {
     [1] = { "stuff" },
     [2] = { "more stuff" },  
     [3] = {
        [1] = "deeper stuff"
     }
  },
  ["table: 000001A7E014F570"] = "Updated Stuff"
}
```

While if I then call `print(data[{2,3,1}]` I get the correct value but If I then try to recursively loop through the table using ipairs I get the original value and the extra is ignored. I know that from a Lua sense this should be possible but just cant see the forest for the trees.

I guess I'm looking for the Lua equivalent of lodash's `_.set(table, "path.to.key", value)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should implement also `__newindex` metamethod

```
local data = {
   [1] = {
       [1] = { "stuff" },
   },
   [2] = {
      [1] = { "stuff" },
      [2] = { "more stuff" },
      [3] = {
         [1] = "deeper stuff"
      }
   }
}

setmetatable(data, {
   __index = function(t, k)
      for i, k in ipairs(k) do
         if t == nil then return nil end
         if type(t) ~= "table" then error("Unexpected subtable", 2) end
         t = rawget(t, k)
      end
      return t
   end,
   __newindex = function(t, k, v)
      local last_k
      for i, k in ipairs(k) do
         k, last_k = last_k, k
         if k ~= nil then
            local parent_t = t
            t = rawget(parent_t, k)
            if t == nil then
               t = {}
               rawset(parent_t, k, t)
            end
            if type(t) ~= "table" then error("Unexpected subtable", 2) end
         end
      end
      rawset(t, last_k, v)
   end
})

print(data[{2,3,1}])
data[{2,3,1}] = "updated stuff #1"
print(data[{2,3,1}])
data[{3,1,2}] = "updated stuff #2"
print(data[{3,1,2}])
```

Answer (score 1):

`print(data[{2,3,1}])` indexes data and hence invokes your `__index` metamethod which then returns the string `"deeper stuff"`

`data[{2,3,1}] = "updated stuff"` is an assigning index operation. It would invoke `__newindex`, not `__index`.

As you don't have a `__newindex` you're just doing a regular assignment with the table `{2,3,1}` as table key.

You have to implement `__newindex` if you want use the table's contents as keys to index `data[2][3][1]`.

I'm not sure why you prefer `data[{2,3,1}]` over `data[2][3][1]`. You're adding uneccessary confusion. The few cases where it would be conveniant to provide table keys in a table could be solved using a simple function that takes both the table and a list of keys. But that's just my personal opinion.
I just showed you what is possible im my last answer. That doesn't mean it's a good idea to do it :) Sorry if that was not clear.

You could simply have two functions:

`updateDeep(t, newVal, ...)` and `getDeep(t, ...)` that can be implemented similar to the __index metamethod. replace `k` with `{...}`

Comment: Thanks for the input.  The problem for me is that its a user defined data structure and I am recursively working with the dataset so it could have N levels of depth but I need to be able to access the nodes via the path down the tree branches.